# Fitting model again after variable selection

Tags: machine-learning, model-selection, model-evaluation, regression-strategies

This question has been asked quite a bit in other contexts (doing LASSO then OLS on selected variables for example), but I'm unsure about how to proceed for this case.

Suppose I have a set of 50 predictors for one outcome. I then split my data in two parts, train and test.
I then train a random forest on the training set and compute variable importances. 
I select the 10 most important predictors.

If I now wanted to retrain a model with just these 10 predictors (because I need a simpler model than just one with all predictors), how would I go about it?

Is it "OK" to just use the training set again? Would this not result in some sort of overfitting? What is the correct way to fit the smaller model and then assess performance?

Answer (score 1):

You can fit again the model considering only the 10 selected features but I think that, whenever possible, you should shuffle the train and test sets again, fit the "simple" model with the new train data and use your new test set for model validation.

Also, when doing the feature selection, I would repeat the process a few times with different train-test splits, to check for consistency in which variables appear the most relevant

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was already doing your second suggestion (i.e. stability selection) !

Regarding the first suggestion, would you suggest to do a split  Train1, Train2, Test? 
You select variables on Train1, fit the smaller model on Train2 and then assess performance on Test?

Comment: If you have enough data, sure!

Comment: This is a fairly dangerous procedure and needs a double bootstrap or nested cross-validation to validate it.  Note that you are acting as if the confidence intervals on variable importance have zero width.  Variable importance is a very unstable quantity.

Comment: @FrankHarrell Sure! That's why you should fit a few times with different splits!

Comment: Whatever you do, the learn about the stability of the analysis you need to use completely "starting over" resampling or have a large completely independent holdout sample from which simple resampling can estimate the confidence intervals on feature importances.  There is a limit to how much the data can inform one about the information content of specific features in the data.